# Storing native language strings in SQL columns with user defined datatypes

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

My Table name is `property_pair_master`. And one of the column in it is

`prop_value` (its `datatype` is `varchar(max)`);

I created my `userdefined` `datatype` using the below query

```
EXEC sp_addtype 'tinyUTF8','varbinary(8000)','NULL'
```

Now I changed the `datatype` to my tinyUTF8 (my defined `datatype`).

Problem is when I am trying to update the value in it using the below query

```
update property_pair_master set prop_value =
CONVERT('મારું માહિતી પરીક્ષણ' AS tinyUTF8) where id=1
```

getting the error message as

```
Incorrect syntax near 'મારું માહિતી પરીક્ષણ'.
```

How can I update the String into `Database`?
Is there any alternative to do this. Any suggestions ?

Note : I am using `SQL SERVER 2008.`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it *MYSQL* or *SQL-SERVER* ? Looks like SQL Server but edit your tags

Comment: In MsSQL the `source as targettype` syntax is for `CAST()` not `CONVERT()`

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: I tried with CAST also .Same result :(

Comment: [`sp_addtype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189784(v=sql.100).aspx): "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work..."

Comment: [`CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx): "... the target data type. ... Alias data types cannot be used."

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk Thank you for valuable suggestions .

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for corrected my syntax.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the update Damien(:)) .Sure ,I will find out an alternative .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HHHahh...

I found the `solution` and got rid off `cast and convert`

Updated the datatype to `nvarchar(MAX)` .And I updated my query as

```
update property_pair_master set prop_value = N'વ્યાવહારિક' where id=1
```